# End of script output before headers: wsgi.py

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to install my django project with Apache, mod_wsgi and python3. 
 but Apache still gives this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from    '/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1288, in _shutdown
assert tlock is not None
AssertionError:
End of script output before headers: wsgi.py
```

I lost two days trying to fix this problem, I know that this error can be produced by several reasons but I not find where the problem.

Here the **wsgi.py** content:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os
import site, sys

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/myproject_env/bin/python3.4/dist-packages')
site.addsitedir('/var/www/myproject/myproject_env/bin/python3.4/dist-packages')

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myproject.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The Apache configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    Alias /static/ /var/www/myproject/static/
    Alias /static/admin/ /var/www/myproject/static/admin/
    Alias /uploads/ /var/www/myproject/uploads/

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject lang='fr_FR.UTF-8' locale='fr_FR.UTF-8' python-path=/var/www/myproject:/var/www/myproject/myproject_env/bin/python3.4/dist-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

     <Directory "/var/www/myproject/myproject/">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /static/admin/>

            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Location "/uploads/">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myproject.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myproject.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please anyone helps me fix this?

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: that's all it gives. some times it shows only this : `End of script output before headers: wsgi.py`

Comment: There's there any other place where I can find other logs except those apache??

Comment: Well this error dump you have posted doesn't actually look like it came from the apache logs. Did you take it from /var/log/apache2/myproject.log? How have you setup logging in your django settings?

Comment: Yes, I take it from /var/log/apache2/myproject.log, but i have no idea about setup logging in django settings! Please how can I add it and how it will serve me?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: I changed the location of my Django project to another folder in a new linux account. I think (and I'm not really sure) the error occurred because **/var/www** contains another python project using cgi-bin, this maybe creates conflict with my Django project.